# Downloading WikiMapia in Google Earth

Tags: coordinate-system, google-earth, wikimapia

Previously I was able to download the WikiMapia KML and install it in Google Earth perfectly, but right now it is not working with me.

Is there any new update or new link that I'm not aware of?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the KML that is causing the issue, so we can take a look?  Or is your question about not being able to find the link anymore?

Comment: I used to use this link https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TtY1m9wZx2iCXD6UvgZ8qI5p07KtW4s8/view
But currently it is not working,

Comment: That link just worked for me... I was able to download a KML file.  The file works in Google Earth Pro (desktop version), but not in the newer Google Earth web version.  I'll put more info into an Answer.

Answer (score 0):

The link in the comments downloads a valid KML file, which works fine in Google Earth Pro (the desktop application).  The file contains a single NetworkLink, which dynamically loads KML content from a service on the wikimapia.org servers, based on your current view window.  In other words, the NetworkLink request from Earth to their server includes a bounding box for your current view, so that it can load a limited and reasonable amount of data (since the whole database is too large to load at once).

Unfortunately that KML does not work in the newer Google Earth web version, for two reasons...

First, when loading the Networklink KML it returns a "blocked:mixed-content" error (in the Chrome dev console) due to the fact that the NetworkLink points at "**http**://wikimapia.org/...".  If I edit the file to point at "**https**://wikimapia.org/...", then the request goes through.

But then it hits the second issue, which is that the wikimapia server is not set up with cross-origin request support (they don't provide the correct CORS headers), which would allow the code in Earth web to request the files.  This is something that the folks who run the wikimapia server will need to fix, before their file will work in Google Earth on the web.

For now, if you want to use this KML file, you'll need to view it in Earth Pro, which can be downloaded using the links at the bottom of this page: https://www.google.com/earth/versions/